# Generar filas nuevas basadas en condiciones pandas

Tags: pandas, condiciones

Tengo que crear una nueva columna que su resultado está basada si se cumplen ciertas condiciones.  Por ejemplo:  fecha, código y país.  Encontré una solución aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172463/python-pandas-conditional-subtraction

El código que se utiliza es el siguiente:

```
d = {'Country': ['France', 'Honduras', 'Honduras', 'France'],
     'Trade': ['Exports', 'Exports','Imports', 'Imports'], 'Code': ['941010', '951510', '951510', '941010'], 'Value': ['100','200','500', '50']}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
pd.concat([df.set_index(['Country', 'Trade'])
  .groupby('Country')
  .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0]-x.iloc[1])
  .assign(Trade='Result')
  .set_index('Trade', append=True),
  df.set_index(['Country', 'Trade'])]).reset_index()
```

Logré correr el código, pero no es lo que necesito.

Con el dataframe de arriba se alcanza:

[image: Resultado]

Sin embargo, en la columna de código no aparce el correspondiente (debería ser por ejemplo para France 941010 o para Honduras 951010.  Cualquier ayuda se agradece de antemano.

Esto sirve para calcular un dataframe de millones de registros, que tienen que cumplir ciertas condiciones para poder restarse.

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. En este sitio no resolvemos tareas y/o proyectos. Para cada pregunta es necesario que agregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Incluido el código